# NtQueryInformationFile(FileStreamInformation) fails with STATUS_END_OF_FILE

Tags: driver, windows-kernel

I deal with application that scans files at a location (identified by UNC path) and gathers various bits of information about them. One of such bits is a list of alternate files streams -- which gets retrieved via `NtQueryInformationFile(..., FileStreamInformation)` call.

This works for untold number of files with exception of very few -- for those few (mostly `jpg` originated from some camera, but also `docx` and `zip`) that function call fails with STATUS_END_OF_FILE. I can't find any explanation of why. There are other files in same directory(ies) that have no such problem, `dir /r` shows no alternate streams, `copy` works fine. Data corruption is very unlikely.

I would appreciate any ideas that may explain this. Thank you.

More info:

- target is located on VNX 7500 (maybe a bug in their SMB server implementation?)
- NTFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went wrong with alternate streams. Listing them fails, but if you copy file -- it arrives to destination without any alternate streams (and application works with copied file without problems). I suspect OS copy operation silently ignores alt stream-related failures and (if they happen) doesn't copy them.

So, basically, copying files elsewhere and copying them back (overwriting originals) fixes the problem.